# Cannot read all DBF file data properly, but i see some of that data in file opened as text editor

Tags: dbf, xbase

I have a data files from an old software that is still in use. My week long researches show that this file type might be <FoxBase+/dBase III DBF type. File from that software came with extension ".STA". Opened with excel this file shows most of data, but not all.[image: ExcelFragment]

What is interesting that, I see data which is not shown with excel simply opened in [image: Notepad]

Data that is missing in "excel" is a components data of each operation. Main Operation data is shown, but consisting components are not. This is why I am trying to access it.

I tried different .Net packages to get properly that data, but no results more what I see in excel. DBF viewers shows same data, except different last column representation. I get something like: "XB++\u0002\0\0\0\0F\u0001\0\u000e\0\0\0�t\0\0\u0001\0\0\0\u0003�;\a]f\0\0\v\u0004�;\abm"

I would greatly appreciate any insights how could I properly access to data that fragments are shown as simple text file open.